# Python class string type argument showing up as float type

Tags: python

I would appreciate if someone can help me figure out what I have done wrong. One of the arguments in my SupportDocument class is called preferred_name. It represents the preferred name of a file. I have a method that determines whether to use the original name or the preferred_name. When run the program, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

... at this step of the code:

```
    elif len(self.preferred_name) > 4:
        target_name = self.preferred_name
```

The thing is that the values for preferred_name are strings. The values are retrieved from an excel sheet and I have verified there are no floats.

I was able to go around the error by simply changing the above to:

```
        elif len(str(self.preferred_name)) > 4:
            target_name = self.preferred_name
```

However, I am still trying to figure out what I have done wrong in initializing the class so that preferred_name could be interpreted as float type.

The relevant code is below.

Thank you.

SupportDocument:

```
class SupportDocument(object):

    source_link: object

    def __init__(self, source_link, original_name, target_dir, preferred_name=''):
        self.source_link = source_link
        self.original_name = original_name
        self.target_dir = target_dir
        self.preferred_name = preferred_name

    def get_full_url(self):
        full_url = home_page + self.source_link
        return full_url

    def get_target_full_dir(self):
        if self.target_dir is None:
            target_full_dir = settings.DEFAULT_DOC_DIR
        elif len(self.target_dir) > 3:
            target_full_dir = os.path.join(settings.TARGET_ROOT_DIR, self.target_dir)
        else:
            target_full_dir = settings.DEFAULT_DOC_DIR
        return target_full_dir

    def get_target_name(self):
        if self.preferred_name is None:
            target_name = self.original_name
        elif len(str(self.preferred_name)) > 4:
            target_name = self.preferred_name
        else:
            target_name = self.original_name
        return target_name

    def download(self, session):
        target_path = self.get_target_full_dir()
        os.chdir(target_path)
        schema_get = session.get(self.get_full_url(), verify=False)
        file_name = self.get_target_name()
        with open(os.path.join(self.target_dir, file_name), "wb") as code:
            code.write(schema_get.content)
```

Here is my main():

```
def main():

    doc_count = 0
    with requests.Session() as s:
        authenticate(s)
        df = pd.read_excel(io=settings.DATA_FILE, sheet_name='XpressfeedDocs', usecols='A:D')
        logger.info("Opening data file {}.".format(settings.DATA_FILE))
        dfx = df.head(5)
        for i in df.index:
            source_link = df.iloc[i, 0]
            original_name = df.iloc[i, 1]
            file_name = df.iloc[i, 2]
            target_dir = df.iloc[i, 3]
            doc = SupportDocument(source_link, original_name, target_dir, file_name)
            logger.debug("Starting download of file {}...".format(original_name))
            doc.download(s)
            doc_count += 1
main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/sample_code.py", line 4, in <module>
    from xf_docs import SupportDocument
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\xf_docs.py", line 214, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\xf_docs.py", line 201, in main
    doc.download(s)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\xf_docs.py", line 149, in download
    file_name = self.get_target_name()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\xf_docs.py", line 136, in get_target_name
    elif len(self.preferred_name) > 4:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: a `float` ends up stored in a variable if and only if that variable is assigned a `float`.  It may be useful to simply put `self.preferred_name = str(preferred_name)` in `__init__` if you don't feel like tracking it down further back in the code.

Comment: Show your code that produce the error, not just the class definition. Full traceback would also be helpful. Although @Scott's suggestion would mask this particular problem, I doubt preferred file name would be a float, i.e. you need to investigate further why you get float when expect string.

Comment: @khelwood - sorry about that. I corrected the indentation.

Comment: @buran - Thanks. Added the main() function and the traceback.

Comment: Just put a call to print with what is being extracted from the spreadsheet. Chances are it isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: Especially, what is the *SupportDocument* initialization value of `file_name`?

Comment: @JaredSmith - I inspected the spreadsheet. There are no numbers in it at all. Unfortunately, I cannot post it here.

Comment: @wallyk - file_name is not used to initialize SupportDocument. file_name is the file name to use when downloading the documentation to the target location. It is determined by the method get_target_name(self). get_target_name basically checks if a preferred_name has been entered and if it is not, simply takes original_name which is taken from the source. Both original_name and preferred_name are used to initialize SupportDocument. If I have defined __init__ correctly, preferred_name should be an empty string when it is missing at the source. Then, I use len() to check if it can be a filename.

Comment: @assenuma if you refuse to do what we ask, why are you asking us for help? *Put a call to print* above the call to SupportDocument to show what parameters you're passing. "Checking the spreadsheet" isn't going to help.

Comment: Everything you wrote was clear to me from your original question posted.  If you poke around enough to answer my actual question, it is pretty likely you would see the problem and its cause.  My bet is that the value of `file_name` is something like `1.2` or `4e7` or some other floating point constant representation.

Comment: @wallyk - you are absolutely right. When the preferred name field is missing in the excel file, pandas retrieves it as nan, which is float. Thank you! How can I give you attribution for resolving this?